# Callback inside 2 functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, bcrypt

I need to do the callback inside a function thats calling another function inside

```
 exports.user = function(userName, pwd, callback) {
    db.User.findOne({'userName': userName}, function(error, obj) {
        if (error) {
            callback(false);
        }else {
            obj.comparePassword(pwd, function(err, isMatch) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(pwd, isMatch); 
                callback(isMatch); 
            });
        }
    });
};
```

In console i see it's returning true, but callback always return false.
Could u guys help me?

Comment: `but callback always return false` does your callback return anything?

Comment: *"In console i see it's returning true, but callback always return false"* Nothing is *returning* anything in that code. Do you mean you see `isMatch` is true? If so, you're absolutely calling `callback` with `true` on the next line.

Comment: Sorry! like u said, I see `isMatch` true

Comment: When i call that function, callback is returning false

Comment: @JoãoPedroBretanha In that case you need to show the callback method definition. And in your code, callback's return is not being printed at all.

Comment: `user.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, cb) {
     bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
         if (err) return cb(err);
         cb(null, isMatch);
     });
 };`

Comment: Thats the definition of my callback function

Comment: Sorry for indentation :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Sorry, guys! But the problem was in my frontend. I was getting answer from the wrong route. Thank u